# Calculate the phase angle

Tags: oscilloscope, electrical

I have a question about the sign of Δt :

Why is Δt in in this one positive
[image]
And negative for this one below  ?

[image]                             [image]

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, it is clear that the reference for the phase calculation is the blue trace so that Δt is measured from the blue trace zero crossing to the black trace zero crossing which is positive. In the second example, Δt is not shown so the reference trace is not clear.  I would assume, in this case, that the red trace is the reference and Δt id measured from the red zero crossing to the dotted trace zero crossing which is negative.

Comment: Assuming that I don't have the reference and I want to calculate the angle phase ? How will I know which reference is the correct one ?

Comment: There is no correct one.  As long as you specify what you are doing, the result will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If the dashed violet sinusoid is \$4 \cdot sin(2\pi\cdot t/10)\$, then the orange sinusoid can be represented as

\$4\color{red}{/2} \cdot sin(2\pi\cdot t/10\ \ \color{red}{-\pi/2})\$

where \$\pi/2 \leftrightarrow 90^{\circ}\$.

The orange signals *lags* the violet signal by 90 deg.

In the case of triangle wave, if we try to represent the black triangle in terms of the blue triangle, the black triangle *lags* the blue triangle by 80 deg; i.e. \$\phi = -80^{\circ}\$.

\$black(t) = \frac{1}{2}\color{blue}{blue}(t - 2/9)
= \color{blue}{blue}(t \color{red}{- 80/360} \cdot T)\$

However, if the blue triangle is represented in terms of the black, blue *leads* black by 80 deg.

\$\color{blue}{blue}(t) = 
2\ \cdot\ black(t \color{red}{+ 80/360} \cdot T)\$

Calculation of phase depends on which signal is used as the reference.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with phase measurement (especially in test procedures) it is always advisable to clearly state how you expect the phase to be measured

"positive going zero crossing of CH1 to the next positive going zero crossing of CH2" contains the three pieces of information

1. what is the reference waveform - ie CH1
2. Which zero crossing event (since there is two )
3. where to measure the phase difference from

This will always give you a positive phase value as it is measuring left to right.

Looking at the two waveforms in question, none of this information is stated and thus assumptions must be made (reasonable assumptions but assumptions nonetheless)

**Image 1**

assuming BLUE is the reference waveform:  1st positive going zero crossing is at t=0. The 2nd waveform positive going zero crossing, after the 1st, is at t=2 divisions

thus (2-0)/9

**Image 2**

Based upon the statement that a negative value is measured, the reference waveform is ORANGE.  1st positive going zero crossing is at 2.5. The 2nd waveform positive going zero crossing is at 10 divisions

Thus (10-2.5)/10

Also note -90deg = +270deg